# modrewrite - rewrite to new domain from subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Damn you modrewrite

I have a website hosted at a url like:

http://mydomain/mocks/thesite/

Now I want to move it to a new domain

http://thesitesdomain.com/

My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thesitesdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.thesitesdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now this works fine as long as there is something after `/mocks/thesite/`. eg: `http://mydomain/mocks/thesite/index.html` redirects to `http://www.thesitesdomain.com/index.php`.

However the problem is that:

`http://mydomain/mocks/thesite/` redirects to `http://thesitesdomain.com/mocks/thesite/`. Any idea why? How to stop this?

The .htaccess file is in the root of `/mocks/thesite/` (if that helps)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the variable REQUEST_URI you might have a little more success with that. It should be the request uri and file name. To

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thesitesdomain\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.thesitesdomain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I can't remember but to also redirect with the query string (get variables) I think you need to add it like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thesitesdomain\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.thesitesdomain.com/%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Been a while since really doing a domain redirect....

BTW this is a good read on htacces configuration:
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: Your answer isn't right unfortunately, thanks for your help though. I've pinpointed the issue though (I think). It appears that when there is a match (eg: `(.*)`) then the `$1` references that match. When there isn't a match for that (ie: nothing after `mocks/thesite/`) then the `$1` references the whole request uri. Any way to stop this?

Comment: I'm at work now but will make a little test case when I get home, no way this should be hard :|